# A question about sample events and binomial probability

Tags: probability, independence

!Disclaimer: Since English is my second language, I apologize beforehand if my writings aren't that coherent.

So I'm having some problems understanding the question of this particular problem, extracted from book "Applied Statistics and Probability for Engineers" by Douglas C. Montgomery. The exercise is:

> Six tissues are extracted from an ivy plant infested
> by spider mites. The plant in infested in 20% of its area. Each
> tissue is chosen from a randomly selected area on the ivy
> plant.

> (b) What is the probability that three out of four successive
> samples show the signs of infestation?

Here is a short solution as to how i solved this problem:

1. First of all there are 3 events that has 4 successive samples.
2. From each of those said event, there are ${}_4C_3$ more events of which there are 3 infested samples.
3. From that it seems like there are 12 different events to be accounted for. For each event, there would be 3 infested (20% occurrence) and 3 uninfected (80% occurrence) samples.
4. Let $P(F)$ be the result that satisfy the given question, we have:
   $$P(F) = 12*0.2^3*0.8^3$$

However, the textbook solution I got from [quizlet](https://quizlet.com/explanations/textbook-solutions/applied-statistics-and-probability-for-engineers-6th-edition-9781118539712/chapter-2-exercises-151-b4fa7eb9-3c7c-4ddc-a63a-191798e6bf20) says that there are two events that would be counted twice, one of which is:

Where $A_1$ to $A_4$ is a 4-successive-sample group and $A_2$ to $A_5$ is another one. Both events have a similar case where $A_1 \cap A_2' \cap A_3' \cap A_4' \cap A_5 \cap A_6$

So according to the solution this case is only counted once, but isn't $A_1-A_4$ and $A_2-A_5$ are different events? Therefore even if both event has the same case, it shouldn't matter. And that conflicts with the solution I saw. Which would be the correct one?